# Jenkins Master on VM Linux Centos and Jenkins Slave on VM Windows 7

Tags: maven, jenkins, centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Texte d'origine  Ecoutez le texte source
Hi

Please, can you give me your opinions about this subject :

1.I have instaled Jenkins on VM Linux Centos
2.I have installed Jenkins on VM Windows 7 which contains the project Java Maven.
3.I shared the project from VM Windows 7 to VM Linux Centos and I succed to the project from my VM Linux

My goal is to make Jenkins Master on VM linux and Jenkins slave on VM Windows.

What I should do for creating the communication between all jenkins.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of making a Windows slave (after defining nodes on master), on Windows server:
-browse to Jenkins node listing and launch web agent (Java Web Start) which has to be done manually each time the server starts up
-after starting the agent, register the slave as a service

Plenty of documentation, I found [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) just now.

Definitely prefer a service you don't have to worry about the web agent dying for some unknown reason and no one noticing, much better to have it auto start.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you I followed your documentation but when I arrived in the step 5 : Now you need to connect your slave machine to the master using the following steps.

    Open a browser on the slave machine and go to the Jenkins master server url (http://yourjenkinsmaster:8080).

Comment: Hi Scott, Thank you I followed your documentation but when I arrived in the step 5 : Now you need to connect your slave machine to the master using the following steps. It doesn't work.The @ IP of the master is 10.1.0.144 and 10.1.0.137 for the slave.In the VM Windows slave .

Comment: need more info than "it doesn't work", what are you doing and what are you seeing?  Can the machines in question even ping one another?

Comment: yes the machines can ping one another but the ping from the master to slave didn't finish

Comment: from the slave I can't launch the master with this url :http://@serverMaster:8080

Comment: unless you've got a typo, the URL should be "http://serverMaster:8080/" or (depending if you're running a servlet engine like tomcat "http://serverMaster:8080/jenkins" or something like that.  It'll be the same used to manage it from your desktop.  Otherwise, you have a network issue that's preventing the master and slave from seeing each other.

Comment: Hi Scott, I resolve the problem but when I arrive in the 6th step, I didn't found in the Jenkins slave agent the menu of File .In your opinion what should I do ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure without looking at the system, when I did attempted it was 1,2.3.  Are you sure the launch method is correctly defined?  Otherwise, not sure I know.

Comment: for more details; I haven't File in the "Jenkins slave agent" for clicking on  File --> Install as Windows Service. Thank you in Advance for your help.